# checkbox checked from database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a edit form. All the data is loaded to the form but the checked box data is not working means that all the checkboxes are not checked. In the database the are stored as 1,2,3,4 as this format. I try this `string[] AccessId = access.AccessId.Split(',');` so that the data can be splinted.

**This is the View**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AccessList.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (i % 3 == 0)
                            {
                                <br />
                            }
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => r.AccessList[i].IsChecked)
                            <label>@Model.AccessList[i].AccessName</label>
```

The controller

```
var access = _context.Requisitions.SingleOrDefault(s => s.JobID == id);
string[] splitAccessId = access.AccessId.Split(',');
```

Is there a way that I can archive this